# How put a UIView above the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, keyboard

I have a idea to hide some keys in keyboard. I use the exact background of the keyboard and use it above the keyboard.

So I create a textView and add a accessoryView

```
 //Create the view 
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -10, 768, 300)];
 [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]

 UITextField text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 80, 28)]; 
 [text setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
 [text setInputAccessoryView:view];
```

[image]
This really hide the keyboard, but if I click in this view, the button still show. I try to use a UIButton, but the button don't catch the click. And I try `becameFirstResponder` when `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and no success.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `userInteractionEnabled` to YES for your accessory view. This will make your view swallow all the touches.

If you want a custom view for editing, though, you can do this by setting a specific editing view for your field rather than trying to put something else on top of the keyboard.

Comment: I do not find the `userInputEnable`, instead find `userInteractionEnabled`. But, I use it and do not work.